# Крайний или последний (не в очереди)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Тут уже был вопрос о том, как правильно говорить "кто крайний" или "кто последний", а я немного о другом.
Я всегда говорю "последний" о последнем предмете, событии или явлении в ряду. А некоторые говорят "крайний" (крайний раз и т.д.). Что правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какая разница, что "не в очереди"?
В любом случае литературная норма - "последний".
"Крайний" говорят либо люди, с испорченным чувством такта (это как раз в очереди), либо представители некоторых профессий из суеверных соображений. Последних я иногда могу понять, но только не в общелитературном язвке.